# JQuery UI Slider not sliding when min value is not set to zero

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have implemented the JQuery UI Slider and i thought it was working, but on further testing, if the min value set is not zero, the slider appears but does not allow you to pull the handles.  I can see that something is trying to happen when one of the handles has focus and you try and drag, but they then just stay rooted to their initial positions, if i change the min value to 0, this then works but this is not the behavior i need the slider for.

CurrentMin and currentMax are just persisted values so i can set the default state of the slider if they are not the original min and max, so these could be the variables for the slider initialisation:

```
var min = 100,
    max = 500,
    currentMin = 120,
    currentMax = 450;

   $("#slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        values: [currentMin, currentMax],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            'Do Something Awesome...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Am unable to replicate it as you described. Modified from jQuery UI Slider Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xuud5152/

Comment: Your fiddle put me on the right track.  i upgraded the JQuery UI version which then threw an error.  I forced the values through parseFloat and that resolved it!